# Desktop screen turns off then on when the room light comes on/off

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, display

I have an AOC Intl monitor, 23 inch, resolution 1920x1080, that connects to the computer via HDMI cable. It works as well on my desktop with Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 10 dual boot.

And for both OSes, I got the same strange behavior: when I turn on the (only) neon light in my room, the monitor is always automatically becoming black within a few seconds. It looks like it activates some self-regulating mechanism. After that, it will restore normal state.

When I turn off the light, the same thing also happens.

And that happens even in daylight.

[image: aoc display]

What's that feature? How to disable it? How to keep the monitor always-on without modifying its state like that?

Comment: Sounds like interference from the fluorescent light. How is the monitor connected to the computer? HDMI? I have a TV at home that does the same thing. Any electrical noise causes it to lose sync and blink out for a couple seconds. You can try a different HDMI cable. Or maybe move the monitor to a different electrical outlet or further away from the fluorescent light. You need to do some troubleshooting. I don’t think this has any thing to do with a “feature.” You may have to just live with it or buy a different monitor.

Comment: That sounds like the feature for an ambient light sensor on the PC/monitor, however I'm not sure how to disable it on Ubuntu _(in Windows, it's within the Power Control Panel applet)_

Comment: Thank you all, it connects to the computer via HDMI port. I just found that it happens even in daylight, so it may not relate to light sensor or something like that? I just added more info to my question.

Comment: I'm with @appleodditty for this. Change the lamp, or put a ferrite bead on the monitor power cable.

Comment: Switch off  `ambient light sensor` if it turned on in power options

Comment: `ambient light sensor` can be also activated in BIOS

Comment: Thank you @Alex I would try at next boot and let's you know if it works.

Comment: @Alex I could not find any option relating to light sensor in the bios setting interface. My computer was built on top of MSI B360M Bazooka mainboard.

Comment: The only explanation then - it is bad grounding shield and absents of power line suppression filters in monitor that able to clamp high voltage spikes. Neon lights works using high voltage transformer to fire up neon gas ionization that on start and end produce short high voltage "backfire" spikes to power line and monitor's filters don't filter this noise and as result provoke internal mainboard restart/reset. Unfortunately many manufactures eliminates such filters in power supplies due to economy and as result such systems becoming victims.

Comment: It's not your system, it's the electric circuit - turning the neon on/off causes a spike. I had similar problem with my HDMI monitor. Every time my fridge compressor turned on or off caused my monitor to "reboot". In my case the solution was twofold: 1. connect the monitor to a different outlet and 2. get a good quality HDMI cable instead of a cheapo one.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your spike guard is the culprit. Even my screen blinked for the last 4 years while i someone switch on fan or light. I thought it was hdmi to dvi converter which caused the screen to go off. But the thing is that hdmi and dvi have the same signals and the only difference is hdmi cables transfer sound signals also if you have speaker in your monitor. So the convertor was not the problem as it is just an extention without an adapter. My monitor dosen’t have a hdmi port thats y i used a convertor. Yesterday i bought a good quality spike guard from GM modulars company on amazon and now my screen dosent go off. Also the culprit may be cheap hdmi cables. buy good quality hdmi cables and spike guard.